# Xamarin, Xiaomi и странная отладка

Tags: android, xamarin

Есть Xamarin for Visual Studio. Я создал приложение Xamarin.Forms. Запускаю его на телефоне(Xiaomi Redmi 3) и вижу свою честно выполненную работу... Завершаю отладку кардинально изменяю свой код, запускаю... И вижу свою предыдущую версию приложения. Трижды перезапускаю и вижу прежнюю версию. Психую. Закрываю Visual Studio и запускаю снова. Повторяю предыдущие действия и снова вижу самую первую версию. Жалуюсь своему коту...

По совету своего кота, приступаю к устранению этой ошибки. Удаляю приложение на своем телефоне и запускаю отладку вновь. Вот другой результат. Приложение как только запустилось, сразу закрылось. Ну хоть что-то. Перезагружаю телефон, удаляю приложение, запускаю отладку и тут вижу желанный результат - все что я сделал работает! Ну при последующем изменении и запуске возникает та же ошибка.

Приходится перезагружать телефон каждый раз. Но до этого я видел превосходно работающий Xamarin без регулярных перезагрузок телефона! Как предотвратить ошибку? Как не тратить время на отладку? И откуда взялась это ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Проверенное мной решение - делать ребилд перед каждой отладкой.
Также проверьте, включены ли инструменты разработчика в настройках (много тапов по build.number), и поиграйте с опциями отладчика xamarin (use shared runtime). Также [см. тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/debugger-settings). У меня в дебаге включено use shared runtime, выключено fast deployment.